# C# size of a form should depend on a handed over variable

Tags: c#, variables, size

I have two forms ( "Startfenster" and form1). First Startfenster opens and the i can write two variables ( "Rohrdurchmesser" and " Messlanzen") which i deliver Form1. Form 1 has 2 pictureboxes and 5 buttons. the size of the picturboxes should depend on variable "Rohrdurchmesser" which works, but the size and minimum size of the second form ( form1) should also depend on "Rohrdurchmesser", which doesn't work... Here is a part of my code...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
                {       
                    Startfenster fh;
                    int Rohrdurchmesser, Messlanzen;
                    ...
                    Bitmap bmp;
                    Graphics z;


                    public Form1(Startfenster aufrufer) // Startfenster was the first Form, which opens first when you start the program
                    {
                        fh = aufrufer;
                        InitializeComponent();
                        Anordnen();

                        bmp = new Bitmap(pic1.ClientSize.Width, pic1.ClientSize.Height);
                        z = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);          
                        Startfenster.ActiveForm.Hide();       

                    }

                    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {            
                        Rohrdurchmesser = Convert.ToInt32(fh.Controls["txbRohrdurchmesser"].Text);
                        Messlanzen = Convert.ToInt32(fh.Controls["txbMesslanzen"].Text);


                        pic1.Height = Convert.ToInt32(PixelToCm(Rohrdurchmesser)) * Rohrdurchmesser;
                        pic1.Width = pic1.Height;
                        pic2.Height = Convert.ToInt32(PixelToCm(Rohrdurchmesser)) * Rohrdurchmesser;
                        pic2.Width = pic2.Height;

                        Form1.ActiveForm.Size = new Size(2 * pic1.Width + 40, pic1.Height + 60); // doesn't work! why? 
                        Form1.ActiveForm.MinimumSize = new Size(2 * pic1.Width + 40, pic1.Height + 60);// doesn't work! why? 
                    }

          private void Anordnen()
                {

                    pic1.Width = this.ClientSize.Width / 2 - 30;
                    pic2.Width = this.ClientSize.Width / 2 - 30;
                    pic2.Left = pic1.Right + 20;
                    btnVergleichen.Left = pic1.Right + 10 - btnVergleichen.Width / 2;
                    btnEinlesen1.Left = pic1.Left + pic1.Width / 2 - btnEinlesen1.Width / 2;
                    btnBewerten1.Left = pic1.Left + pic1.Width / 2 - btnBewerten1.Width / 2;
                    btnEinlesen2.Left = pic2.Left + pic2.Width / 2 - btnEinlesen2.Width / 2;
                    btnBewerten2.Left = pic2.Left + pic2.Width / 2 - btnBewerten2.Width / 2;          

                }
      double PixelToCm(double Pixel)
            {
                double cm = -1;
                using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
                {
                    cm = (Pixel / g.DpiY) * 2.5399999d;
                }
                return (double)cm;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean 'Doesn't work' ?

```
  Form1.ActiveForm.Size = new Size(2 * pic1.Width + 40, pic1.Height + 60); // doesn't work! why? 
  Form1.ActiveForm.MinimumSize = new Size(2 * pic1.Width + 40, pic1.Height + 60);// doesn't work! why?
```

Shouldn't this be

```
  this..ActiveForm.Size = new Size(2 * pic1.Width + 40, pic1.Height + 60);  
  this.ActiveForm.MinimumSize = new Size(2 * pic1.Width + 40, pic1.Height + 60);
```

or some real form reference, not the class name?